# How to apply an animation to a matplotlib plot using PyQt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm trying to make an algorithm visualizer using python, pyqt5, and matplotlib and when I started applying the algorithms animation I always get an error saying:

```
File "F:\Programmes\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 264, in broadcast_arrays
    shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
  File "F:\Programmes\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 191, in _broadcast_shape
    b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

I started with bogo sort (lol) but failed because I was bombarded with errors so I left it and tried quick sort, it works in the backend but when I try to apply the animation or anything else with it, it crashes

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from interface       import Ui_MplDialog
import sys
import random


class Canvas(FigureCanvas):

    # Setting up the width, height and dpi of the canvas (matplotlib)
    def __init__(self, parent = None, width = 5, height = 5, dpi = 100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.plotdata()

    # plotting the actual data !
    def plotdata(self, xdata = 0, ydata = 0):
        self.x_data = xdata
        self.y_data = ydata
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.ax.cla()
        self.ax.set_title('IM VERY FUCKING TIRED!!')
        self.ax.bar(self.y_data, self.x_data)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()


class MainWindow(QDialog):

    # Initialization Stuff like PyQt5 and Matplotlib
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MplDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=7.2, height=2.1)
        self.canvas.move(0,210)

        # Variables Initialization
        self.algo = None
        self.x_data = []
        self.y_data = []

        # The Start, Stop and Random buttons functions bindings
        self.ui.pushButtonPreview.clicked.connect(self.preview)
        self.ui.pushButtonStart.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.ui.pushButtonRandom.clicked.connect(self.random)

        # Setting the 'Quick Sort' Radio button to be CHECKED by default to avoid user error
        self.ui.radioButtonQuickSort.setChecked(True)

        # Number of Operations Counter
        self.counter = 0
        self.ui.labelNumOfOp.setText(str(self.counter))

        # Radio Buttons functions bindings (throw an Error if there is no Algo selected)
        if   self.ui.radioButtonBogoSort.isChecked(): self.algo = 'BogoSort'
        elif self.ui.radioButtonHeapSort.isChecked(): self.algo = 'HeapSort'
        elif self.ui.radioButtonQuickSort.isChecked(): self.algo = 'QuickSort'
        elif self.ui.radioButtonMergeSort.isChecked(): self.algo = 'MergeSort'
        elif self.ui.radioButtonShellSort.isChecked(): self.algo = 'ShellSort'
        elif self.ui.radioButtonBubbleSort.isChecked(): self.algo = 'BubbleSort'
        elif self.ui.radioButtonCocktailSort.isChecked(): self.algo = 'Cocktailsort'
        elif self.ui.radioButtonSelectionSort.isChecked(): self.algo = 'SelectionSort'
        elif self.ui.radioButtonInsertionSort.isChecked(): self.algo = 'InsertionSort'
        else:self.showError('Please Select an Algorithm')

    # Start plotting the Algorithm
    def preview(self):

        # ----- Part 1 : Value checks and error throwing -----

        # init'ed a Empty list to hold a shuffled (n) of elements
        try:
            if int(self.ui.lineEditNumOfInt.text()) > 0: # Checks if it is a Negative Int
                if int(self.ui.lineEditNumOfInt.text()) <= 100: # Checks if it is Lower than or equal to 100 if not throw an Err

                    # Clearing the data_x and data_y lists
                    self.x_data.clear()
                    self.y_data.clear()

                    # Generate a list of length (n) then append every Element to the empty list after that we shuffle it
                    for i in range(0, int(self.ui.lineEditNumOfInt.text()) + 1): self.x_data.append(i); self.y_data.append(i)
                    random.shuffle(self.x_data)
                    self.canvas.plotdata(self.x_data, self.y_data)      

                else: self.showError('Please Enter a Number Lower Than 100!')
            else: self.showError('Please Enter a Positive Number!')
        except ValueError: self.showError('Please Enter a Number!') # if the Value equals a string or a Non-int value

    # Generates a random number of int for it to be plotted (Max: 100) (for performance reasons...)
    def random(self):
        self.ui.lineEditNumOfInt.setText(str(random.randint(5, 100)))

    # Stops the Algorithm Visualizer
    def start(self):

        ani = FuncAnimation(self.canvas.fig, self.canvas.plotdata, interval=1000)

        # ----- Part 2 : Algorithm type checking and plot init'ing -----
        if self.algo == 'BogoSort':
            self.bogoSort(self.x_data)
        if self.algo == 'HeapSort':
            pass
        elif self.algo == 'QuickSort':
            self.quickSort(self.x_data)
        elif self.algo == 'MergeSort':
            pass
        elif self.algo == 'ShellSort':
            pass
        elif self.algo == 'BubbleSort':
            pass
        elif self.algo == 'CocktailSort':
            pass
        elif self.algo == 'SelectionSort':
            pass
        elif self.algo == 'InsertionSort':
            pass
        # else: raise Exception('Something is not right!') # NOTE: Raise Exception


    # ----- Part 3 : Algorithms themselves

    # 1: Bogo Sort
    def bogoSort(self, nums):
        pass

    # 2: Quick Sort
    def quickSort(self, sequence):
        length = len(sequence)
        if length <= 1: return sequence
        else: pivot = sequence.pop()

        items_greater = []
        items_lower = []
        entire_seq = [items_lower] + [pivot] + [items_greater]

        for item in sequence:
            if item > pivot: items_greater.append(item); self.counter += 1
            else: items_lower.append(item); self.counter += 1
            self.ui.labelNumOfOp.setText(str(self.counter))
            self.canvas.plotdata(entire_seq, self.y_data)
        return self.quickSort(items_lower) + [pivot] + self.quickSort(items_greater)


    # Throws an Error on the screen
    def showError(self, str):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: share interface-py, change to `self.ani`

Comment: @eyllansec i don't understand what do you mean